# Why AngularJS filter matches incomplete values

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I'm getting incomplete values when trying to use `ng-model` + text input as search bar.

As an example : When I write "li" in the text input I get the results back "B Lifting", but when I try to write "lifting" it will show no results. If I write "kl" I can get up "Gulklokken", but if I search for "Gulklokken" it won't show the result.

I can't seem to figure out the reason for it.

Code for search bar :

```
   <div id="searchBar" class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.hovedkunde" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-blur="focused = false">
    </div>
```

Code to display results :

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-if="search.hovedkunde" ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
                <table class="table table-hover">

                    <tr>

                        <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'hovedkundE_ID'; reverse=false">ID</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'hovedkunde'; reverse=false"> Hovedkunde</a></th>
                        <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'lonG_NAME'; reverse=false">Kundenavn</a></th>
                        <th></th>

                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="pro in filtered = (projects | filter: search) | sliceArray:bigCurrentPage*pageSize | limitTo : pageSize | unique:pro.projectId | orderBy:predicate:reverse ">

                        <td ng-click="setInfo(pro.projectId)">{{pro.hovedkundE_ID}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="setInfo(pro.projectId)">{{pro.hovedkunde}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="setInfo(pro.projectId)">{{pro.lonG_NAME}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="setInfo(pro.projectId)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve</button></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination" boundary-links="false" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmm. The project is for a client and there is a lot of sensitive data involved. What do you need on the fiddle? You can't see anything wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: I don't have enough information - how did you decleaed the 'search' filter used in (projects | filter: search)

Comment: search is from the ng-model. It´s not declared anywhere else. Should it be? It´s not a custom filter in that sense, I am only using ng-models value as the filter.

Comment: Try using $ to search among all properties.

Comment: ng-model="search.$", right? I have tried it and it gives the same problem. Only gives me some of the results.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` expression allows you to specify a *comparator*.

---

*Comparator* which is used in determining if the expected value (from the filter expression) and actual value (from the object in the array) should be considered a match.

Can be one of:

`function(actual, expected)`: The function will be given the object value and the predicate value to compare and should return true if the item should be included in filtered result.

`true`: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(expected, actual)}. this is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

`false|undefined`: A short hand for a function which will look for a substring match in case insensitive way.

---

In your case, you should define the `filter` like this

```
filter:search.hovedkunde:true
```

Comment: I tried using true, but that will only show me the 100% equal value. Like if I search for "Soda" it will return all values names "Soda", but will not show "Sodapop","Sodabottles" etc. Maybe false|undefined is what I am looking for?

Comment: So that´s just filter:search.hovedkunde:false?

Comment: Feel free to try multiple options and see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me getting a better understanding of how filters works. But the problem seemed to be the pagination from Angular UI. :)